# Facebook Feed Grabber Cache Relative to Dev Machine, not Server Install

Tags: plugins, facebook

One of our devs left last week and I inherited some tasks for one of his projects. I've never really worked with WordPress and I am not overly familiar with PHP (I am an app dev), so I am completely lost here. Basically, our Facebook feed (which is using the [Facebook Feed Grabber](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-feed-grabber/) plugin) will not display. When I went into the admin panel in our testing environment, it said the following:

[image]

I am assuming this is the issue. We cannot cache any data therefore no data can be displayed. The path is relative to the old dev's work env and I cannot get it to change. After some digging, I found a line in the `facebook.php` class that seems to be the setting for that option.

```
'cache_folder' => WP_CONTENT_DIR. '/uploads/cache/',
```

I also tried changing that to `content_url( 'uploads/cache' )` as well and ended up with the same result. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Change your permission to 664 to the uploads and its cache directory inside.
Learn more [**here**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions).